How is it possible for a kafka listener to be part of multiple kafka containers?
this spring kafka docs says:

Obtaining the Consumer group.id
When running the same listener code in multiple containers, it may be
useful to be able to determine which container (identified by its
group.id consumer property) that a record came from.

Given a java piece of executing kafka listener code, I am assuming the listener can be part of only one factory either default or the one specified in the @KafkaListner annotation.
But given the earlier quoted statement from kafka docs, seems there is more to it.
How can I make a listener to be part of multiple containers?

That's maximum what I can find about that option: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1026. Probably that means when you use multiple @KafkaListener methods in the same service.

You can create listener manually (without using annotation) and assign it to different container using container.setupMessageListener.
See more on that here.
